# How to make code to manipulate string on specific condition in javascript using loops?

Tags: javascript, string

here I'm having a JSON data after JSON parsing we can take data property as string

```
data:"BUSINESS.id,BUSINESS.stokens[],BUSINESS.plist(BUSINESS.inventory),BUSINESS.bslist(BUSINESS.srvinventory),BUSINESS.sur(USER.store.roles.role)[{scdate,sudate,rid,urname,sid,suid}]"
```

and I need to split it by specific requirement

```
text = BUSINESS.id,BUSINESS.stokens[]
list = BUSINESS.plist(BUSINESS.inventory),BUSINESS.bslist(BUSINESS.srvinventory)
object = BUSINESS.sur(USER.store.roles.role)[{scdate,sudate,rid,urname,sid,suid}]
```

make sure that while programming don't consider BUSINESS as string could be also

```
data:"id,stokens[],plist(inventory),bslist(srvinventory),sur(USER.store.roles.role)[{scdate,sudate,rid,urname,sid,suid}]"

text = id,stokens[]
list = plist(inventory), bslist(srvinventory)
object = sur(USER.store.roles.role)[{scdate,sudate,rid,urname,sid,suid}]
```

make code for this string in javascript

I tried to split code based on (",") but it does not satisfy the requirement as we need to make code separately for text, list, and object

please divide string on given requirement

the text has only . or []

list have only ()

an object is a combination of ()[{}]

Comment: will the same type of filters comes together or they can be jumbled?

Comment: they can be jumbled

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `regex` with `String.prototype.match`

```js
let data = "BUSINESS.id,BUSINESS.stokens[],BUSINESS.plist(BUSINESS.inventory),BUSINESS.bslist(BUSINESS.srvinventory),BUSINESS.sur(USER.store.roles.role)[{scdate,sudate,rid,urname,sid,suid}]";
let out = data.match(/(.*\[\]),?(.*\(.*\)),?(.*\(.*\).*\[\{.*\}\]),?/);
console.log(out.slice(1,4))
```

```js
let data = "id,stokens[],plist(inventory),bslist(srvinventory),sur(USER.store.roles.role)[{scdate,sudate,rid,urname,sid,suid}]";
let {1: text, 2: list, 3: object} = data.match(/(.*\[\]),?(.*\(.*\)),?(.*\(.*\).*\[\{.*\}\]),?/);
console.log(text);
console.log(list);
console.log(object);
```

Comment: it works only when text, list and objects are in sequence, if there in no sequence then this regex not works properly

Comment: that's what I asked you here [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57721446/how-to-make-code-to-manipulate-string-on-specific-condition-in-javascript-using/57723047?noredirect=1#comment101883834_57721446)

Comment: can you please provide me any regex which can work on a mixed string?

Comment: just make regex for below string **which not consider BUSINESS** and consider mixed string